# onPostExecute does not being called on AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have seen all similar questions here on SO and I am using AsyncTask in other activities but in only this one the onPostexecute is not called.

here is my code after hours oof trying.

```
class GetCamera1Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                CameraGallery.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(int result) {
            System.out.println("onPostExecute");
            this.dialog.dismiss();


        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bitmapResult1 = getBitmapFromURL(url[0]); 
            bitmapResult2 = getBitmapFromURL(url[1]);
        }
            System.out.println("should return");

            return 1;
        }

    }
```

where all the variables are global variables.
The should return is being printed but the onPost execute is not called.

I have also tried my onBackground to return null and the sceleton to be like this:

```
class GetCamera1Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
protected void onPostExecute() {
}
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
... return null;
}
}
```

but again nothing.

The code for downloading the bitMap from url is this:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same question and answer : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449438/asynctask-onpostexecute-not-being-called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining the generic parameters as `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>`, but then use `int` in `onPostExecute()`. Try replacing

```
protected void onPostExecute(int result)
```

with

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
```

Answer (score 3):

`onPostExecute()` is called on the main UI thread. If its not getting called and you have tried all other tricks mentioned above, it means your UI thread is blocked doing something else.

Comment: This was answered 2 years ago.

Comment: i know but the way it solved my problem is not mentioned here. Added so that it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Override` to your onPostExecute() method.  It will highlight that you haven't overridden it properly. Then change it to:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
```

and you should be good to go.